# Extracting the value from Netcdf file with longitude and latitude

Tags: python, netcdf

I would like to extract temperature values from model output with python.

My model output have separate temperature, longitude and latitude variables.

So, I overlap these three grid variables on one figure to show temperature with longitude and latitude through model domain.

Up to this point, everything is fine. The problem is to extract temperature value at certain longitude and latitude.

Temperature variable doesn't have coordinate, but only values with grid.

Do you have idea about this issue?

Here is my code for the 2 D plot with temperature on model domain:

```
varn1 = 'T2' 
varn2 = 'XLONG' 
varn3 = 'XLAT' 
Temp  = read_netcdf(filin,varn1) 
Lon  = read_netcdf(filin,varn2) 
Lat  = read_netcdf(filin,varn3) 

Temp_plt =  Temp[12,:,:] 
Lon_plt = Lon[12,:,:] 
Lat_plt = Lat[12,:,:] 
x = Lon_plt 
y = Lat_plt
```

---

read_netcdf is a code for extracting values of [time, x,y] format.

I think that the point is to bind x, y in Temp_plt with x, y in Lon_plt and Lat_plt to extract temperature values with longitude and latitude input.

Comment: The netcdf grid should have enough metadata to place the grid geographically, letting you translate from grid to geo (lat-long, UTM, etc) as desired. This question is probably better posed in gis.stackexchange.com. The GDAL package includes functions for parsing the netcdf file; I don't know which package you're using that include "read_netcdf"

Comment: read_netcdf is a code to read netcdf file including simple modules from netcdf4 such as MFdataset and Dataset and command variables().

Comment: My question is whether there is any efficient way to combine one variable and another variable from NetCDF. In this case, longitude/latitude and corresponding temperature without using other external package. Do you think that is is possible? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it's possible. It's probably not advisable. Why do you not want to use a debugged, well-regarded, external package? And why does that reasoning apply to gdal but not to python?

Comment: The reason is because I am not that familiar with gdal. Also, I thought that it would be more convenient if I can do everything in samecode of python. Thank you.

Comment: if you spend the time you're now spending on netcdf familiarity on gdal familiarity, you'll be ready for not just netcdf, but a host of other GIS files